# In Shore Leave were replicants sentient?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

These were very sophisticated devices but iirc, definitely not alive. But just as Data and some other characters that were meant to replicate humans to an extent were, they could have been sentient.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure "replicant" is the correct word here? Memory Alpha refers to "replicants" as being biological creations, while the Shore Leave characters are "robots", and says that "replicant" wasn't used to describe anything in Star Trek until Deep Space Nine.

Comment: It is the word I used because they copy specific humans. Every time I have met a copy of an existing person, I called it a "replicant" to its face and they did not seem to mind although sometimes they had a flat affect and were difficult to read.